# What is the jni/libs folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have noticed that when adding native support to a project in Eclipse, it generates a jni/libs/ folder. What is this folder and how is it used as I cannot find it in the NDK documentation.

From the NDK docs,

> a copy of your prebuilt shared library will be copied into
>   $PROJECT/obj/local, and another will be copied and stripped into
>   $PROJECT/libs/(abi).

I notice that when a do an `ndk-build`, this dir gets cleaned out and a few libraries are put in it. Yet, it usually is not the case that the libraries in $Project/jni/libs match $Project/libs. Also it  seems that when I install an application, jni/libs is not referenced.

Is jni/libs just a temp folder used by ndk-build? Is it documented anywhere, or is this an vestige of using Eclipse for native support?

Comment: "jni/libs" seems a bit odd.  Usually jni/ would contain *source* code of native libraries (or at least the instructions for finding it), while libs/ would contain the results, both intermediate stages and final .so output.  Is there any chance you inadvertently have eclipse *uselessly* building jni code for the development host (as if you were doing noromal non-android java work), in parallel to the ndk *usefully* building it for your android target?

Comment: Did your project have `jni/Android.mk` ***before*** you clicked _Add Native Support_?

Comment: @AlexCohn there is no jni folder until you either add one manually or click Add Native Support

Answer (score 4):

jni/libs folder is where  your shared library files are built from the C/C++ sources. Your native code gets compiled and depending on the value you had set in your application.mk file for the parameter

```
APP_ABI: = <all | x86 | armv7a | armeabi-v7 | mips>
```

the corresponding libs.so files are generated and places in jni/libs folder. These lib files are bundled to your final apk file and referenced by your app as and when needed. This is not a temp folder and the files from this folder does go into your final apk file.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see this in the NDK documentation, instead I see the NDK docs reference $PROJECT/libs/abi as the folder that goes into your apk.

Comment: abi is what refers to x86,arm,mips etc. Different folders are created for each architecture.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I do not see jni/libs mentioned in the NDK documentation, only $PROJECT/libs is mentioned.